# What is the counter name for verbments?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, fancyvrb, verbments

I'm trying to use the [`verbments`](http://ctan.unixbrain.com/macros/latex/contrib/verbments/verbments.pdf) package with the [`cleveref`](http://www.dr-qubit.org/latex/cleveref.pdf) package. I need to find the name of the counter which is usually used for `\ref{listing_label}` to be able to define the name `cleveref` uses for it.

Comment: The counter is `pllisting` whereby the definition takes part at after `begin{document}`

Comment: @benregn If my answer solved your issue, would you kindly consider marking it as "accepted"? Thanks `:-)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only counter that appears in [`verbments.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/verbments/verbments.sty) is `pllisting`. Maybe that's the one?

Comment: If one doesn't know what counter to use in the first argument of `\crefname`, it's sufficient to try `\cref{<label>}` which in this case produces ``cref reference format for label type `pllisting' undefined``, so that it's clear what counter name is to be used. Can you also add the suitable `\crefname` declaration?

Comment: @egreg Does "you" mean me? 'Cause I've never heard of `\crefname`. But feel free to edit my answer of course.